# Dynamic array of strings in C is not working properly

Tags: c

I'm somehow having troubles creating a dynamic array of strings in C. I'm not getting the expected results and I want to know why ?

readLine() function will read each line seperately and will do some changes if necessary :

```
char *readLine(FILE *f, size_t *len)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    ssize_t nread;

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((nread = getline(&line, len, f)) != -1)
    {
        if (line[nread - 1] == '\n')
        {
            line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
            *len = strlen(line);
        }
        return line;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

readFile() function will return an array of strings after reading all of the lines using readLine and then storing them into an array of strings :

```
char **readFile(const char *filename, size_t *fileLen)
{
    char  *result;
    int    idx   = 0;
    char **array = calloc(1,  sizeof(char*) );

    if (filename == NULL || fileLen == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        result = readLine(f, fileLen);
        if (result == NULL)
            break;
        else
        {
            *(array + idx) = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char *));
            strncpy(array[idx], result, strlen(result) + 1);
            idx++;
            array = realloc(array, (idx + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

In main I created a temporary file to test my functions but it didn't work properly :

```
int main()
{    
    char   filename[] = "/tmp/prefXXXXXX";
    int    fd;
    size_t len = 0;
    FILE  *f;

    if (-1 == (fd = mkstemp(filename)))
        perror("internal error: mkstemp");

    if (NULL == (f = fdopen(fd, "w")))
        perror("internal error: fdopen");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        fprintf(f, "%d\n", i);
    fclose(f);

    char **number = readFile(filename, &len);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]); i++)
        printf("number[%i] = %s\n", i, number[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program, I get the following output:

```
 number[0] = 0
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: If `readFile` returns `NULL`, `array` is not `free`d. This is nonsense: `*(array + idx) = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char *));` First of all, it would be much more readable to use `array[idx]`. Second, `array[idx]` points to `char` you should use `* sizeof (char)` or just drop that because the size is always 1. Finally, how is `LENGTH` related to `strlen(result)`? And also: Using the length of the source for `strncpy` does not make sense anyway. You can use `strcpy` with identical result.

Comment: You have lots of problems with your code. You should start using a debugger and see what values you are dealing with at each instruction. You should also test each function separately instead of putting everything together and just check the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of issues in that code, it's difficult to find where to start...

Let's look at each function.

```c
char *readLine(FILE *f, size_t *len)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    ssize_t nread;

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((nread = getline(&line, len, f)) != -1)
    {
        if (line[nread - 1] == '\n')
        {
            line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
            *len = strlen(line);
        }
        return line;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

There is not much wrong here. But [manpage for geline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) tells us:

> If *lineptr is set to `NULL` before the call, then `getline()` will
> allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be
> `free`d by the user program even if `getline()` failed.

You do not `free` the buffer if `nread==-1` but only do `return NULL;` possibly causing a memory leak.

You should also check whether `len==NUL` as you already do it with `f`.

Then look at the next function:

```c
char **readFile(const char *filename, size_t *fileLen)
{
    char  *result;
    int    idx   = 0;
    char **array = calloc(1,  sizeof(char*) );

    if (filename == NULL || fileLen == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        result = readLine(f, fileLen);
        if (result == NULL)
            break;
        else
        {
            *(array + idx) = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char *));
            strncpy(array[idx], result, strlen(result) + 1);
            idx++;
            array = realloc(array, (idx + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

In this function you fail to `free(array)` in case you hit a `return NULL;` exit.

`readLine` puts `strlen(result)` into `filelen`. Why don't you use it to allocate memory? Instead you take some unknown fixed length `LENGTH` that may or may not be sufficient to hold the string. Instead you should use `fileLen+1` or `strlen(result)+1` as you do it with `strncpy`.

You are also using size of wrong type. You allocate a pointer to `char`, not `char*`. As size of `char` is defined to be 1 you can just drop the size part here.

Then, the length parameter for `strncpy` should hold the length of the destination, not the source. Otherwise it is completely useless to use `strncpy` at all.
As you already (should) use the string length to allocate the memory, just use `strncpy`.

Then, just passing `fileLen` to the next function does not make sense. In `readLine` it means length of a line while in `readFile` that would not make any sense. Instead it should mean number of lines. And as we just came to the topic... You should pass some value to the caller.

Finally, you should not assign the return value of `realloc` directly to the varirable you passed into it. In case of an error, `NULL` is returned and you cannot access or free the old pointer any longer.

This block should look like this:

```c
        {
            array[idx] = malloc(fileLen+1);
            strcpy(array[idx], result);
            idx++;
            void *temp = realloc(array, (idx + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            if (temp != NULL)
              array = temp;
            // TODO: else <error handling>
        }
    }
    *fileLen = idx;
    return array;
}
```

This still has the flaw that you have allocated memory for one more pointer that you do not use. You can change this as further optimization.

Lastly the `main` function:

```c
int main()
{    
    char   filename[] = "/tmp/prefXXXXXX";
    int    fd;
    size_t len = 0;
    FILE  *f;

    if (-1 == (fd = mkstemp(filename)))
        perror("internal error: mkstemp");

    if (NULL == (f = fdopen(fd, "w")))
        perror("internal error: fdopen");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        fprintf(f, "%d\n", i);
    fclose(f);

    char **number = readFile(filename, &len);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]); i++)
        printf("number[%i] = %s\n", i, number[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

`char **number = readFile(filename, &len);` You get an array holding all the lines of a file. `number` is a very poor name for this.

You `return NULL` from `readFile` in case of an error. You should check for that after calling.

Then you forgot that arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. They behave similar in many places but are very different at the same time.

`i < sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0])`

Here `number` is a pointer and its size of the size of a pointer. Also `number[0]` is a pointer again. Different type, but same size.
What you want is the number of lines which you get from `readFile`. Use that variable.

This part should look like this:

```c
    char **all_lines = readFile(filename, &len);

    if (all_lines != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            printf("all_lines[%i] = %s\n", i, all_lines[i]);
```

And you should not forget that you have allocated a lot of memory which you should also free.
(This might not strictly be necessary when you terminate your program, but you should keep in mind to clean up behind you)

```c
    if (all_lines != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            printf("all_lines[%i] = %s\n", i, all_lines[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            free(all_lines[i];
        free(all_lines);
    }
```